# Device (iMX6) is not available from external network

Tags: linux, ping, lighttpd, yocto, imx6

I use a iMX6 with a linux-mainline kernel 4.1.36 and busybox 1.24.1.
For UMTS connection I use the SARA-U201 (with a telekom SIM-card). Its connected over usb (for ethernet) and rs232 (for config) with the iMX6.

After config:

```
root@phyboard-mira-imx6-3:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:2D:F4:08:2C:F5  
          inet addr:192.168.3.11  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::522d:f4ff:fe08:2cf5%1995589328/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8315 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8743 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:664958 (649.3 KiB)  TX bytes:1128987 (1.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1%1995589328/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1225 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1225 (1.1 KiB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:96:86:B3:86:52  
          inet addr:10.18.207.86  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4496:86ff:feb3:8652%1995589328/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:72542 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:108670738 (103.6 MiB)  TX bytes:3776406 (3.6 MiB)

root@phyboard-mira-imx6-3:/# dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
80.187.122.57
```

The ethernet connection is established (e.g. I can get data with wget and can ping google.de).

My problem is, that the iMX6 is not available from an external network. It can't get pinged with the global inet addr (80.187.122.57) and the http-server (lighttpd) isn't available too.
The setup of the lighttpd works in the local network, but not over the usb0 connection.

First I patched the lighttpd to bind the server on a specific interface (in my application the usb0), but the iMX6 is still not available. So I thought it is a basic config problem.

Next I changed the routing-table.
I added to the default Gateway a destination host with the same IP-address and the subnet-mask 255.255.255.255. (described in http://www.fibel.org/linux/lfo-0.6.0/node477.html, routing-table for a router). But the iMX6 is still not available.

I don't know what I could try next. :/

Comment: Check your firewall settings.  To test, from the local machine, try to connect to the external IP explicitly using wget.  If you can not connect, then something on the local machine is preventing the connection.  The other thing to check is `netstat -lnt` to make sure that lighttpd is listening on port 80 (or whichever port you have configured) on '*' or on the IP you configured.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast response. The telekom sim-card was the problem -.- I got a private IP from telekom ... so my device was connected to the  internet but only in one direction. With another APN config in the u-blox I solved the issue. Now I get a public IP and the webserver works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong APN settings in the u-blox device. My device got a private IP from the provider.
I changed the APN to get a public IP -> webserver works.